# Build meego image using ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, meego

I want to build meego image using ubuntu . Where i have all the rpm to my local machine. 
 how to build image using downloaded RPMs in a folder . 
 Is there any change has to be made in mic-image-creater or any special command has to be followed.

Thank you